# why both the consoles.log are giving same output

Tags: javascript, function, this, console.log

```js
function sum(){
  console.log(this);
}
 
var sum1= new sum();
console.log(sum1);
```

I getting sum{} sum{} as output and I am verymuch confused with this result

Comment: what would you expect?

Comment: What else would you expect? You're constructing an instance, and logging it twice.

Comment: Inside the contructor function, `this` is the new object being constructed. This is the same object that it returns automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting two outputs because the `new` keyword actually executes `function sum()`

See the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description):

> 3. Executes the constructor function with the given arguments, binding newInstance as the this context (i.e. all references to this in the
>    constructor function now refer to newInstance).

Answer (score 0):

when you create a function it creates its own internal instance (`this`)

when you use `new` with your function it will return this internal instance.

here's an example that illustrates that it is the same instance, which is why the console log is showing the same.

```js
function sum(){
  this.a = 1
  console.log(this);
}
 
var sum1 = new sum();
console.log(sum1);
```

Note that if you don't use `new` the behaviour changes. In this case, the `this` is the global context and the returned value (and 2nd log result) is `undefined`

```js
function sum(){
  this.a = 1
  console.log(this);
}
 
var sum1 = sum();
console.log(sum1);
```

to the best of my knowledge, this constructor function syntax was introduced into JS as a way to do classes, where it serves as a class constructor. Here is some additional reading that may help  https://javascript.info/constructor-new#constructor-function

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript function can be used as a constructor.

Eg you can define constructor:

```
function Cat(color) {
   this.color = color
}
```

and use them as

```
const cat = new Cat("black");
```

So:

In first example you have this as instance of object that you initialising. You can use this `this` to create his properties. That object is returned if you use keyword `new`.

so in my example you will see in constructor:

```
this = {} // before assignment
this = {color: "black"} // after line this.color = color
```

and when you will use `new` you will see ready cat

```
{color: "black"}
```

in some browsers you will see also name of constructor. In my case `Cat`, in your `sum`.

---

Note that there is convention to use big letter as names of functions that are constructors. You will see syntax with `class`. It is only syntactic sugar that under the hood using functions to define constructors.